# Water replacement on a world with a nitrogen-rich atmosphere

Tags: chemistry

The planet in question is [this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/72840/sky-color-on-a-planet-with-an-atmosphere-consisting-mainly-of-nitrogen). The atmosphere mainly consists of nitrogen and is approximately a quarter the density of Earth's; I chose surface temperatures ranging from -50°C to 0°C.

I need a compount which effectively "replaces" water on this planet. Any compounds similar to Water in their composition and their chemical reactions, with oxygen replaced by nitrogen, are welcome; I looked up Azanide (H2N) but could not find information about its chemical and physical properties.

A modification of the surface temperature is allowed, which means that compounds with evaporation temperatures between -100°C and -50°C are permitted too. The difference between the melting and evaporation temperature must be as big as possible.

Comment: I doubt if azanide would be a replacement for H2) (water) as this web page suggests it is a molecular subunit of proteins and other complex molecules: https://www.wikigenes.org/e/chem/e/2826723.html

Comment: FWIW, earth's atomosphere is [78% gaseous nitrogen](http://www.space.com/17683-earth-atmosphere.html) already.  I'd call that "mainly nitrogen".  You're going to need to come up with a good reason why the (relatively stable) diatomic nitrogen would be found in other forms.

Answer (score 8):

Replacing Oxygen with Nitrogen pretty much gets away all the reasons for the peculiar properties of water: highly polar molecule with strong H bonds between molecules, resulting in its relatively high boiling point.

The closest small molecule is ammonia, NH3, which melts at -78 °C and boils at -33 °C. In your indicated temperature range you could have seas of ammonia and gas, but no solid ammonia.

But your planet is less dense, therefore it will have a lower gravity if the size is similar to Earth. A lower gravity means a lower pressure, and therefore you can wave goodbye to your liquid ammonia.

Comment: Looked up a phase diagram. http://www.cpp.edu/~skboddeker/122/exam/122-07-4fall-e2_files/image005.jpg

Comment: The highly polar nature of water isn't simply useful because of its influence on melting and boiling points; It also makes water useful as a solvent for a variety of ionic and polar molecules.  It also causes ice to be (unlike most materials) less dense as a solid than as a liquid.  Ice floats, which allows us to have seas with ice on top that stay mostly liquid.

Comment: Lower gravity does not necessarily imply lower pressure. Titan has much lower gravity than Earth, and higher surface pressure. Venus has slightly lower gravity, and *much* higher surface pressure.